# Make NUnit have unique results <mytest1>.xml instead of TestResult.xml

Tags: nunit, nunit-console

I have a situation where more than one NUnit Console Runner might be triggered on the same VM.

How do I uniquely name my `TestResult.xml` file?

[I do not see an option for this in the docs.](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line)

---

So far, my solution has been to dynamically create the `my_folder` argument in `--work=%my_folder%`, by generating a unique ID in a batch file. Next, I use that ID in a PowerShell script to parse the correct test.

```
set id=%random%_%time%
start "Tests" /D "C:\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.7.0\tools\" "nunit3-console.exe" ^
    "C:\My_Solution\My_Tests\My_Tests.dll" ^
    "--work=C:\test-results\%id%"
powershell "C:\scripts\parse_test.ps1 %id%"
```

It would be MUCH easier to just give the `TestResult.xml` a unique name.

How do I change that name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--result` option of nunit3-console is used to set the name and path of the result file. If you use a relative path, it is saved relative to the directory you specify with the `--work` option.

There is no built-in facility to actually **generate** a unique name or path, however.